# complex sql order by

Tags: sql, mysql

```
id    |    message    |    reply id    |    date  

1     |  my new app.. |     0          | 10 / 10 / 2009 (latest message on top, follow by replies)
5     | love ur app.. |     1          | 11 / 10 / 2009 (this should show under the main message)
6     | another comm  |     1          | 12 / 10 / 2009
2     | application 2 |     0          | 09 / 10 / 2009
3     | reply of 2    |     2          | 11 / 10 / 2009
```

I want to show latest comments and its replies after the main comments. Obviously the replies will have latest date, so I can't sort it by date, because replies will be on top of main. I'm not sure how to do this properly with one query. Any idea's please.

database dump: http://pastie.org/576963

Comment: example if confused: http://pastie.org/577011

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll guess that "reply id" is 0 for articles and is the article number for comments. If that's your design, this should work:

```
select * from yourTable
order by
  case when "reply id" = 0 then id else "reply id" end, id
```

**ADDED:** Thanks for the additional information in your comment. To put the results in the order you want is not so easy, because the first ordering key is the created_date of the thread-starter post. This is not in the data row, so you need a join. Here is my best guess based on the additional information (which is still not complete enough to keep me from guessing):

```
select
  f.id, f.user_id, f.type, f.reply_id, f.text, f.url, f.created_date,
  coalesce(parentfeed.created_date,f.created_date) as thread_date
from feed as f left outer join feed as parentfeed
on f.reply_id = parentfeed.id
order by
  thread_date desc,
  case when f.reply_id = 0 then 0 else 1 end,
  created_date desc, id;
```

You may need to adjust syntax for postgre. I tested this in SQL Server.

If this still doesn't do what you want, please be specific about how you want the data back. Preferably, tell me the "id" order I should see for the data in your dump file, and *also* explain the basis for that order. Here's what I did:

1. All messages in a thread (thread = a messages and its comments) should be grouped together.
2. Within a thread,  put the message on top, followed by  its comments in reverse chronological    order. The thread with the most    recent created/_date should be first,    then the thread with the second most recent created_date, and so on.    (Your sample data had many comments  with the same created_date, so I    used "id" as a secondary order key   for the comments within a thread.)

***Note:*** Your dump indicates that created_date is updated to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP if a post is modified. If this is a live message board, be aware that this might cause comments to be dated *before* the parent message, and it means a thread will stay on top if it is frequently modified (even with no actual change to its text).  (That's not relevant to my solution, but I thought it was worth noting.)

Because a join is required, this query will now be much slower. My suggestion: maintain two date columns, "thread_last_modified" and "item_last_modified". You will have to cascade updates from thread-starters to comments, but I think it's worth it if there are not lots of updates, because the query can be much simpler. I haven't tested this because it requires several changes to your design:

```
select
  id, user_id, type, reply_id, text, url, thread_last_modified, item_last_modified
from feed
order by
  thread_last_modified desc,
  case when f.reply_id = 0 then 0 else 1 end,
  item_last_modified desc, id;
```

**ADDED #2**: If you want only the thread containing the comment with id ::thisOne, I think you can add this line between the ON and ORDER BY clauses (for my first added solution, the join):

```
where parentfeed.id = (
  select coalesce(reply_id,id)
  from feed
  where id = ::thisOne
)
```

In theory, this lookup should be evaluated just once for the query, but if it's not in practice, you could precompute it as ::thisOneThreadID and add

```
where parentfeed.id = ::thisOneThreadID
```

For the second solution, assuming you precompute again, try

```
where coalesce(id,reply_id) = ::thisOneThreadID
```

By the way, I suspect both of my solutions will merge threads that were last modified at the exact same time...

Comment: well i want latest main messages (reply_id = 0) to be on top then right under each reply messages should go. 

- main message
-- reply message
- main message
-- reply message

try the following sql dump file, see if your query works, dont works for me: http://pastie.org/578558

Comment: also please look at the date, dont look at the id, id wont be integer, it will be wired id like youtube (id: CxewVEwed)

Comment: I'm still guessing about what your data means. The dump doesn't help much unless you provide the result you want to see from that data, or a clear description of the order you want to see results in.

What I can tell from your comment is that you'll need a join. The rows of the table do not contain enough information for ORDER BY to solve the problem without a join, because messages have to be ordered according to the date of the parent message. The id, not the date is stored in the row.

I'll add to my original answer.

Comment: this did solve it :). thank you very much. now only thing left is pulling full group with single reply id. hmmm.. please check following link for detail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257890/complex-sql-tree-rows

Comment: Steve, please show me the RDBMS where your first answer, `select * from yourTable
order by
  case when "reply id" = 0 then id else "reply id" end, id` actually works.

Comment: My first answer returns [thread-starter with lowest id], [comments to (thread-starter with lowest id) in id order], [thread-starter with second lowest id], [comments to (thread-starter with second lowest id) in id order],...

Comment: @basit: See the ADDED #2 section of this answer regarding your comment about pulling one reply_id

Comment: @tpdi: SQL Server, for example. This ORDER BY should work for any RDBMS that allows the ORDER BY clause you posted on Aug 8/9.

Are you mistakenly assuming the " characters indicate a string? That would be a problem because the string 'reply id' doesn't represent an integer. However, there are no strings in my ORDER BY; in standard SQL, double-quotes are object name delimiters, not string delimiters. Here they delimit the column name "reply id", which has a space in it.

Does my ORDER BY fail for you on a particular RDBMS? Let me know, since I might have missed some other detail.

Answer (score 2):

....
`order by` *(some predicate which is true for "main comments" but not followups)* `desc, date desc`

Since you don't make it clear what distinguishes a "main comment", that's all I can do for you. If, as in your example, all main comments had a `reply_id` of zero, this might be:

`order by case reply_id = 0 then 1 else 0 end desc, date desc`

Note that using the case statement rather than just ordering by `reply_id` is necessary, because you want the first expression to have the same value (namely, zero) for all non-main messages, so that they are sorted exclusively by the second expression, `date`.

(Oh, if I understand your schema, `reply_id` ought really be named `in_repky_to_id`.)

Comment: This is a useful technique that I use often.

Comment: well i want latest main messages (reply_id = 0) to be on top then right under each reply messages should go. 

- main message
-- reply message
- main message
-- reply message

try the following sql dump file, see if your query works, dont works for me: http://pastie.org/578558

Comment: also please look at the date, dont look at the id, id wont be integer, it will be wired id like youtube (id: CxewVEwed)

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure of your requirements, so my response is an abstraction...
the max - may need to be a min (again, i'm not clear on your exact requirements)

```
select
    y.column1
    , y.column2
    , y.column3
    , y.datecolumn
from
(select 
    column1
    , max(datecolumn) as rank_date
 from tableA
 group by column1) as x
inner join tableA y on x.id = y.id
order by x.rank_date, y...., y.... desc, y... asc, etc...
```

if you are using sql server, there is a function called over row_number that you could use as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link on representing hierarchical data in a relational database.
[http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html](http://web.archive.org/web/20110606032941/http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html)

The gist being, you need to join to the table for as many levels deep you want to go.
The example data provided was just two levels deep.

```
SELECT
f1.id AS `parent_id`, 
f1.text AS `parent_text`, 
f1.created_date AS `parent_created_date`, 
f2.*
FROM 
feed AS `f1`
LEFT JOIN feed `f2` ON (f1.id = f2.reply_id)
WHERE f1.reply_id = 0
ORDER BY f1.created_date DESC, f2.created_date DESC
;
```

The parent article information will be in the f1.* columns and the child information (replys) will be in the f2.* columns.