# Liquibase: SQL syntax error in a MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, syntax, liquibase

I tried to run the MySQL stored procedure SQL script by Liquibase, but never worked.

The content of *db.storedprocedure.xml*:

```xml
<changeSet author="zzz" id="1" runOnChange="true" runInTransaction="true">
    <sqlFile path="changelogs/change_03.sql"
         relativeToChangelogFile="true"
         endDelimiter="$$"
         stripComments="false"
         splitStatements="false"/>
</changeSet>
```

The content of my SQL file *change_03.sql*:

```sql
$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `liqui01`.`User_Search`(
    INOUT id INT,
    OUT name VARCHAR(50)
)
BEGIN

    SET @sql = CONCAT("SELECT id, name FROM user WHERE da.MarketId = ", id );

    PREPARE stmt from @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;

END$$
```

It shows the error like:

> Unexpected error running Liquibase: You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near '$$ ...

I've tried to change the "$$" to other delimiters, or put the SQL inside `<sql>` tags of the XML file, all didn't work.

Any advise would be appreciated!

#### Update 1

@Shadow has given the correct answer (unfortunately I cannot mark it as the answer because it's in the comments), removing the delimeter lines from the sql scripts will make it work, thanks for him!

Now the question is: How to use "endDelimiter" parameter?

Comment: Why do you have an $$ at the start of the stored proc? It is not required. Also note, that this query does not need a prepared statement (this is not related to the error message you received)

Comment: @Shadow Hi man, you saved my time!
Still wonder why "endDelimiter" doesn't work, and why they provide such a parameter ...
I copied the script from other stored procedure, and removed some other parts just for testing liquibase, but forget removing the "prepare stmt" part :)

Comment: Please refer to the complete procedure ->  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267172/mysql-delimiter-error/67905510#67905510

Answer (score 0):

liquibase internals add the `delimiter` command to begin of command, you must remove or comment the fist line with `$$`:

```
-- $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `liqui01`.`User_Search`(

...

END$$
```

Comment: thanks for you advice, but unfortunately it doesn't work, the error message is a little different: ... use near '' at line 12 ... (not "near '$$' ...")

Comment: delete all characters before `CREATE PROCEDURE` and run liquibase.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, but that doesn't work, it shows the same error as in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

I searched the internet for a solution. It appears Liquibase will create stored procedures just fine on the `update` command. But falls apart on the `updateSQL` command as it outputs invalid SQL.

My solution was to add comments to the `changesets sql` tag. With the aim of using regex to sanitize the output sql.

The `.sql` file I am using has some keywords liquibase does not like e.g. `DELIMITER`, so I use `<modifysql>` and `<regExpReplace>` to lint / sanitize the `.sql` file.
This way, the `.sql` file is consumable by liquibase and runs successfully on `update` without errors.

However, we'd still output invalid **SQL** on `updateSQL`. To resolve this, I use another regex search/replace on the invalid outputted `.sql` file looking for the comments; `-- DELIMITER $$` etc.

Example:

```
<changeSet id="Test1" author="author_name" context="master" runOnChange="true">
    <validCheckSum>any</validCheckSum>
    <sql><![CDATA[
        DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_myProcedure`;
        -- DELIMITER $$
    ]]></sql>
    <createProcedure path="yourpath/procs/sp_myProcedure.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />
    <sql><![CDATA[
        -- $$ DELIMITER;
    ]]></sql>
    <modifySql>
        <regExpReplace replace="[^}]+CREATE PROCEDURE" with="CREATE PROCEDURE"/>
    </modifySql>
    <modifySql>
        <regExpReplace replace="END\s*\$\$[^}]*" with="END"/>
    </modifySql>
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the official Liquibase documentation link : [here](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/attributes/end-delimiter-sql.html) which mentions about escaping the delimiter character `$$` like `\$\$`.

> When setting an end-delimiter, note that certain DBMS and operating
> systems require delimiter values to be escaped. For example, a $$
> end-delimiter with mysql requires escaping as: end-delimiter="$$".